# Vim: use different color for words with a pattern

Tags: vim, colors

Am a hardware engineer and I use Embedded Ruby Language to simplify writing my hardware verilog/system verilog code. In my *.sv and *.v files, i have a lot of ERB variables starting with "__" (double underscore). E.g. `<% __MEM_DEPTH = 64 %>`. Is there any way by which I can make vim display the words starting with the double underscore in a different color?

Comment: Persistently or temporarily? Automatically or manually? For every .sv and .v file or just some of them? Do you use built-in syntax highlighting already?

Comment: @Ben: Yes, i use built in syntax (i use verilog based syntax highlighting even for systemverilog files). I don't mind it if I have to do it manually, i can perhaps map it and do it individually for each file.

Comment: I would like the double underscore characters to be shown in a custom color (green or something) rather than have the word highlighted which i think would make much of the file look yellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the built-in syntax highlighting. For example, put the following into `~/.vim/after/syntax/verilog.vim`:

```
syntax match verilogErbVar "\<__\w\+\>"
hi link verilogErbVar Identifier
```

This assumes that the corresponding text fragments aren't yet matched by the original syntax (in my short test, they weren't). Else, you need to find the syntax groups that contain them and add a `containedin=...` to the `:syntax` command.

To find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was messing arround with match and I got this to work decently : match Identifier /__\w\+/

Comment: The nice thing about `:match` is that it doesn't interfere with syntax highlighting; it's always on top. The bad thing is that it's window-local, so it doesn't easily "stick" to the buffer with the Verilog file. If you don't use splits / buffers / tabs much, that may be fine for you (or not).

Comment: I put it in my vimrc file as "autocmd BufNewFile, BufRead *.sv match Identifier /__\w\+/"..This make it automatically use it for all files matching *.sv.

Comment: Yes (and you could also use `:autocmd FileType verilog`). But try `:split` and see that the highlighting isn't there in the second window.

Comment: I tried the split and highlighting happens in both windows with with autocmd I used. I have a follow up question, I have a erb code like this "<%blahblah%>_temp_signal_<%dddd%>"...and i used the "match Identifier /<%.*%>/". Problem is it highlights from the beginning of the FIRST <% to the LAST %> and thus highlights "_temp_signal_" too. How do i make it highlight individual groups of <%%>. Thanks

Comment: That's caused by the greedy `.*` in your pattern. Try `.\{-}` instead. And please don't forget to accept the answer, to mark this question complete!